# Flutter Bloc access response message of an api call in the ui

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm making a post request and returning a success/error message afterwards. I have my state setup like this:

```
import 'package:did_flutter_windows/blocs/createDid/formSubmissionStatus.dart';

class CreateDidState {
  final String firstName;
  final String lastName;
  final String email;
  final String phoneNumber;
  final DateTime? dateOfBirth;
  final String sex;
  final String address;
  final String city;
  final String state;
  final String postalCode;
  final String country;
  final FormSubmissionStatus formStatus;

  CreateDidState({
    this.firstName = "",
    this.lastName = "",
    this.email = "",
    this.phoneNumber = "",
    this.dateOfBirth,
    this.sex = "",
    this.address = "",
    this.city = "",
    this.state = "",
    this.postalCode = "",
    this.country = "",
    this.formStatus = const InitialFormStatus(),
  });

  CreateDidState copyWith({
    String? firstname,
    String? lastName,
    String? email,
    String? phoneNumber,
    DateTime? dateOfBirth,
    String? sex,
    String? address,
    String? city,
    String? state,
    String? postalCode,
    String? country,
    FormSubmissionStatus? formStatus,
  }) {
    return CreateDidState(
      firstName: firstname ?? this.firstName,
      lastName: lastName ?? this.lastName,
      email: email ?? this.email,
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber ?? this.phoneNumber,
      dateOfBirth: dateOfBirth ?? this.dateOfBirth,
      sex: sex ?? this.sex,
      address: address ?? this.address,
      city: city ?? this.city,
      state: state ?? this.state,
      postalCode: postalCode ?? this.postalCode,
      country: country ?? this.country,
      formStatus: formStatus ?? this.formStatus,
    );
  }
}
```

The formstatus represent the different states the Submission can be in. So initial/submitting/success/fail.

```
import 'package:did_flutter_windows/data/models/did.dart';

abstract class FormSubmissionStatus {
  const FormSubmissionStatus();
}

class InitialFormStatus extends FormSubmissionStatus {
  const InitialFormStatus();
}

class FormSubmitting extends FormSubmissionStatus {}

class SubmissionSuccess extends FormSubmissionStatus {
  final Did did;
  final String successMessage;

  SubmissionSuccess({required this.did, required this.successMessage});
}

class SubmissionFailed extends FormSubmissionStatus {
  final error;

  SubmissionFailed({required this.error});
}
```

As you can see I pass in the response message to the status of the form but I don't know how to access that message in the ui. I right now have a BlocListener listen to the formstatus and return a static notification if the submission is successfull or failed. But I want to make the message dynamic and display the message returned from the backend passed to the formstatus.

```
BlocListener<CreateDidBloc, CreateDidState>(
  listener: (context, state) {
    if (state.formStatus is SubmissionSuccess) {
      showSuccessNoti(
          message: state.formStatus.succsessMessage,  //TODO: make mesasge dynamic and display message of formstatus
          context: context);
    } else if (state.formStatus is SubmissionFailed) {
      showErrorNoti(message: "error", context: context);
    }
  },
...
```

Answer (score 1):

if I got you correctly

```
BlocListener<CreateDidBloc, CreateDidState>(
  listener: (context, state) {
    if (state is SubmissionSuccess) {
      showSuccessNoti(
          message: state.successMessage,  //TODO: make mesasge dynamic and display message of formstatus
          context: context);
    } else if (**state is SubmissionFailed**) {
      showErrorNoti(message: **state.error**, context: context);
    }
  },
```

and from the Bloc :

```
  final result = await apiCall() 

yield SubmissionSuccess(state.successMessage: result.message);
```

in this case you will pass from the Bloc to the SubmissionFailed the error you got and will display it as it is from the backend

Comment: Your suggestion is quite simmilar so my current implementation except the state.successMessage to access the message. But the successMessage is not defined in the state. I think I have to get the message from the formstatus but I can't seem to figure out of to access the variable or if it is even possible.

Comment: you can 
you have multi ways to do it for example :

Comment: you can 
you have multi ways to do it for example :

1) define fields (String message....) in the abstract class of the state then you can pass It throw the Super from other states and in that case you got the access to the (message) 

but I didn't get why you can't access the variable SubmissionSuccess